# Cloning specific folder of a repository from Bitbucket

Tags: git, download, directory, bitbucket

I know how to do it in Github but there is no download button to download a specific folder of a repository in Bitbucket. I cannot clone the entire project again as its size is in GB. I know there are some tools to download it but I cannot use them because I need to enter the client repository URL to do that (policy violation).

So, how can I clone the particular folder in Bitbucket?

Comment: BitBucket and GitHub are both Git repository hosts, MAC. Unless you can explain why this is not a duplicate, @chevybow's link will answer your question.

Comment: (Aside: in my experience, the phrase "read my question again" is popular in some English-speaking subcultures. Please note that to British ears (at least), it sounds hostile and patronising. Thus, I recommend you avoid using it if you want a productive exchange with volunteers on the site).

Comment: Sorry for the late update! @chevybow's link solved my problem. Yes! It sounds unprofessional. I will take a note on it.